# Which way is more efficiency to verify multiple Text Fields has been modified?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have a dynamic settings page. It depends on user's scenario, the settings page contents will be varied. I need prompt notice if user modified any setting text field or switcher value. Which way is more efficiency to verify multiple text field strings in customized settings view?

I have two ideas:

1, Traversal all subviews, if subview is textField or switcher, add these strings or boolean values into one NSDictionary obj, and use hash method get the dictionary object hash value and store it. When other event happen, do it again and compare the two hash value. If different, it means some setting is modified.

2, Traversal all subviews, save them into NSDictionary. When other event happen, it will traversal all subviews and compare every text field or switcher value separately. If any comparison found different, it means the settings page has unsaved setting.

Is there any other intelligent way to achieve this goal?

Comment: Implement textfield delegate methods. In the didbegin editing store the current value and in didendediting compare the previous value and current value. If both are different there is a change else no change.

Comment: @MidhunMP Sometime, people changed the value, after while (stay in this view), they change it back. In this case, the settings has no change, but the variable will be mark as changed.

Comment: In that case keep a copy of initial data, change that only when they go back or save the value.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a tag to each control, say from value 1 to 20 (if you have 20 settings). Store the initial value of each setting in a mutable array at the position of the tag value (so if tag is 12, store at position 12). Make a copy of this array, and when they adjust a control store the new value in this second array at the same position (using the tag value as before). Then when they click on save, just compare the values between the two arrays with a simple loop.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, the settings page is still developing, and the objects in the view will be dynamically, depends on user authorities. For the security rasone, it is not good idea that copy settings to other variables. Some people might change a setting, then change the setting back after view other settings. If use a simple flag to indicating changes, the change backed settings will be verified as changed.

My final solution is use md5 hash to snapshot every settings' value, just take lowest 4 chars and xor all snapshots to get one long unsigned integer (NSUInteger) hash value. After view did appear, get this hash value as reference. When user want to save settings or pop to parent view, we do this hash again. Then compare with reference hash value.

#### MD5 Function

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>

- (NSUInteger) md5:(NSString *) input
{
    const char *cStr = [input UTF8String];
    unsigned char digest[16];
    CC_MD5( cStr, strlen(cStr), digest ); // This is the md5 call
    NSUInteger output = [[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedChar:digest[0]] intValue];
    NSUInteger i;
    i =   (0x00000000|digest[3])<<24;
    i = i|(0x00000000|digest[2])<<16;
    i = i|(0x00000000|digest[1])<<8;
    i = i|(0x00000000|digest[0])<<0;
    output =i;
    return  output;
}
```

#### Snapshot Settings

```
- (NSUInteger) hashSettings{
    NSUInteger settingsHash = 0;
    for (NSObject *obj in settingsScrollView.subviews){
        if([obj isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]){
            UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)obj;
            settingsHash = settingsHash ^ [self md5:textField.text];
        }
        if([obj isKindOfClass:[UISwitch class]]){
            UISwitch *switcher = (UISwitch *)obj;
            settingsHash = settingsHash ^ (switcher.isOn?switcher.hash:0xFFFFFFFF);
        }
        if([obj isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
            UIButton *button = (UIButton *)obj;
            settingsHash = settingsHash ^ (button.isHidden?button.hash:0xFFFFFFFF);
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"settings Hash : %@",[self getBitStringForInt:settingsHash]);
    return settingsHash;
}
```

#### For NSLog easily

```
- (NSString *)getBitStringForInt:(NSUInteger)value {
    NSString *bitsSting = @"";
    for(int i = 0; i < 32; i ++) {
        bitsSting = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i%@", value & (1 << i) ? 1 : 0, bitsSting];
    }
    return bitsSting;
}
```